# best practice to retrive entire data or with pagination

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

i have route to retrive the data with pagination in the server i wrote a default values for the offset and limit
when the client call the api it will return the first 10 rows from the Database and it's ok for now
in the dashboard i want to show the entire data to put it in a select
example i have categories and the api call for it return the categories with limit rows and pagination to get the next 10 rows
in the dashboard i want to retrive all the categories without any limit so i can put it in html select element
should i make the route retrive the entire data and the front-end send queries (page-limit) to make a pagination ?
or there is another best practice solution
Express JS & sequlize

try to publish my porblem and expect to get answers and solutions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.